# Creating a % System

Tags: java, javascript

I'm trying to write a system that handles drops for my game, however I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I have all of my drops stored in a 2D Array, which looks like this

```
{MonsterID, ItemID, ChanceOfDrop(1-100)}
```

I have created a dice system that selects a random number between 1-100 as-well, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to make this properly incorporate.

For Instance, lets the item 'Potion' drops 3% of the time.

I have rolled a 7 on my dice.

What is the proper way to do the mathematical check to see if it was done?

I was thinking about doing  roll <= dropRate

But, that made me think, if the drop rate was 80%  and the user rolled and 81, the wouldn't receive it, but looking back at it, that would make something that has a 20% drop chance receive it.

Perhaps I'm over-thinking this and my mathematical eqation of

```
if((RandomNumber(1-100) <= DropRatePercentage(1-100))
```

is the correct way to process this.

Please just fill me in, it's probably due to lack of sleep that I can't get this done correctly, I'm on a dead-line and I've been up for 2 days straight now trying to get everything all set-up, I set a goal to have the Entity/Spawning/Saving/Combat/Drop system done before I stopped.

Comment: Is this Java or JavaScript? Those are two *completely* different languages.

Comment: Also, 81 is less than 20? I didn't know that...

Comment: @Doorknob My brain is so exhausted right now, of-course 81 is not lower than 20, however if 81 <= 20 would be falls, but if 81 >= 20 would be true, BUT...  100-20 = 80, so that gives the item an 80% drop rate if calculated this way. I don't even know.

Regardless of the language, the masth should be done the same.
I displayed Psuedo code, and I don't mind translating, but it's java

Answer (score 0):

Rather than bothering with whatever dice system, simply use the Random class included with Java, and use floats for your chances. Also, assuming that most monsters can only drop a few of all the possible items, your array is very wasteful, storing lots of eg. Chicken -> Iron Ingot -> 0% entries. Instead only store the list of items that can drop and the chance they drop with an array of HashMaps:

```
static Random rand = new Random();
protected Map<Integer, Float>[] allDrops = new Map[numMonsters]; 
//integer = itemID, float = chance of drop (eg 3F/100)

Map<Integer, Float> drops = allDrops[monsterID];
for (Entry<Integer, Float> e : drops.entrySet()) {
    if (rand.nextFloat() < e.getValue()) dropItem(Items.getById(e.getKey()));
}
```

To add a drop to a monster, you'd use

```
allDrops[monsterID].put(itemID, dropChance);
```

Comment: How would I go about adding and amount? Say I wanted to add a MinDrop and a MaxDrop amount for an item.

A Map only allows <K, V> so I can't pass <Int, int, int float>

Comment: Added detail. If you want a more complicated system, you can create a new class with a function that determines how much to drop randomly, and use that in place of the Float.